# Apple iPhone screen problem

Tags: iphone

So I’ve noticed when my hand or anything gets close to the little dot on the screen above the speaker my iPhone screen turns off. It’s not the camera on the back or the front. It’s the little dot above the speaker on the screen.

Is there anyway I can stop that from happening?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. There are several iPhone models available, with different hardware, so which one are you using? And can you describe the location of the problematic spot a bit better as well (maybe include a picture with the area highlighted)?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are referring to the proximity sensor, which is meant to turn the screen off when you are on a call (so that your face doesn't press any buttons). However it shouldn't do it if you're not on a call. Can you clarify when it is doing it?

Comment: It will happen if you are in another app which has implemented the use of this sensor, or is running in the background (you would see a bar at the top).

Comment: It does it any time something get close to it. It doesn’t matter what I’m doing if anything get close to it it turns off